# Questions about Firefox

Tags: discussion

I suspect that [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-can-i-improve-my-ssl-tls-security) might be off topic here as it's not really about Tor. I'm unsure if there's a better SE to ask Firefox related questions on.

Anyone have thoughts? Please vote to close if you think it's off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I actually up-voted the question since it asks about how to improve SSL/TLS connections within Tor Browser without affecting anonymity. The idea that a different TLS setting and different cipher list could be used to fingerprint a user is certainly on-topic, so asking how to improve that within Tor Browser *without* making your fingerprint stand out would seem a valid question to me.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right; it didn't sound to me as if that's what he was asking, but maybe we should leave it to allow for those kinds of answers.

Answer (score 0):

From my impression the questions fits better to [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). I was also thinking about [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), but the question doesn't deal with cryptography itself.